# How to fix Uncaught TypeError in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to submit a form of a specific element in my webpage but i get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
```

This is the JavaScript script for my webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              var aTags = document.getElementsByName("s");
    for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
        aTags[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          bootbox.confirm({
    message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
    closeButton: false,
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Yes',
            className: 'btn-success'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'No',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
      if(result){
        aTags[i].form.submit();
      }
    }
});
        });
            }
              </script>
```

Comment: The error means that `aTags[i]` is `undefined`. Usually submitting multiple forms like that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: i updated the original post

Comment: What is `.form`? Is it a `<form>` tag? Synthetically it looks like is a property of an HTMLCollection (which actually doesn't exist unless it's from bootbox)

Comment: Yeah it's a <form> tag which retrieves the form element of a certain element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every one of the click handlers is referencing the exact same `i` variable. By the time the button is clicked, `i` has long ago been incremented to `aTags.length`. So `aTags[i]` resolves to `aTags[aTags.length]`, which is undefined.

Simplest solution is to just use `let` instead of `var`. That way, every time through the loop gets a new binding of the variable, and thus the click handlers are all associated with the correct value.

```
for (let i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++){
   // rest of the code the same
}
```